# Bitbucket - where to find Repository SSH key?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, bitbucket, aws-opsworks

I am setting up Amazon OpsWorks and I am asked to add a repository SSH key. I host the project on Bitbucket.

As I am clicking through the repository menu options, I don't see there any mention about SSH keys.
So I go to "My Account" -> "Bitbucket Settings" and there's a section called "SSH Keys". I see there the recently added SSH key I added, but when I copy it and put it to the Amazon OpsWorks, it says the key is invalid and I should enter a valid one.

Where to find/generate the SSH key for Amazon OpsWorks to access a private Bitbucket repository?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You generate key using `ssh-keygen`, as the name hints. Amazon probably gives you instructions about the format and more, but assume that it is standard `openssh` format:

```
ssh-keygen -f key -N ''
```

now `key` file contains the private part, that you need to add to Amazon and the `key.pub` contains the public part that you need to add to your BitBucket.

It is not advised to give away your private key that you use to connect from different places (your computer).